# Changing a variable when using dispatch_apply() to parallelize a loop

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have this code:

```
Matrix mat;

for (int y=0; y<n; ++y)
{
    for (int x=0; x<m; ++x)
    {
        // do some small operation on mat(y,x)
    }
};
```

The serial computation is very slow (this double loop is called 500-1000 times), so as a first step I want to parallelize it with `dispatch_apply`.

```
Matrix mat;

dispatch_apply(PATCH_SIZE, _queue, ^(size_t y)
{
    for (int x=0; x<m; ++x)
    {
        // do some small operation on mat(y,x)
    }
});
```

The problem is with the variable `mat`, it's define as read-only inside the block. Is there a way to workaround this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a variable (ref) to be writable from within a block, you can prefix it with `__block`.

For example, `__block Matrix mat;`

Comment: Thanks that works. Will accept the answer when SO lets me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try declaring mat as `__block Matrix mat;`